# Prove that if $f: A→B$ and $g: B→C$ are continuous, then so is $g\circ f: A→C$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I wanted to start by using the definition of continuity.

But my definition is only for $f: A→R$, so I'm unsure as how to write  $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$ for $f: A→B$ and $g: B→C$.

Would it be something like $\lim_{b\to a}f(b) = f(a)$ and $\lim_{c\to b}f(c) = f(b)$

Please let me know if there's a better way to go about this proof

Thank you!

Edit: Changed  $f\circ g: A→C$ to $g\circ f: A→C$

Comment: Is there a metric on $A, B, C$?

Comment: If $A, B$ and $C$ are metric spaces, and $a\in A$. Then $g\circ f$ maps $A\to C$ and you write $lim_{x\to a}f\circ g(x)=f\circ g(a)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that $U$ is open in $C$ and then show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$. Use basic set theory to prove that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U))$. Then $U$ being an open subset of $C$ implies $g^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $B$ and furthermore that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U)) = (g \circ f)^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $A$.

Comment: We have yet to learn what open means. Is there another way to go about this proof?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that if $f$ is continuous, the preimage of an open set is open, and vice versa.

If open sets are not allowed instead you can use the definition of continuity. Let $a \in A$, then
$$ \lim_{x \to a} g\circ f(x) = g(\lim_{x \to a} f(y)) = g(f(a))
$$